# Regex expression assistance email content

Tags: php, regex, email

I have an email, and in this email it has the following content:

Dear Someone,

Thanks for the reply.

Sincerely,

Someonelese

Quoting someone@somewhere.com:

right angle bracket||pipe originaltext

right angle bracket||pipe originaltext

right angle bracket||pipe originaltext

**I need to extract everything from Quoting down to the last right angle bracket OR pipe plus the original text in it**. My theory is to use some regex I want to do a regex for Quoting email then everything below that until the right arrow bracket or pipe end. **I also noticed that sometimes it says "Hide Quoted Text" or "Show Quoted Text" in a link. I wonder If I need to account for that also, or is that part of the email application**

Comment: I have no understanding of what you are saying. I want to do a regex for Quoting email then everything below that until the right arrow bracket or pipe end. What is the index string function

Comment: What email format is delivered to your script?  How is it delivered?  You shouldn't have to account for a "hide quoted text" link except perhaps to strip that line out, but you may have to account for a "show quoted text" scenario where the text is not delivered by default.

Comment: My apologies, I mean the [strpos](http://us3.php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php) function.  Run a loop through the lines of the email, and collect all those after you get a TRUE from `strpos($thisline, "Quoting");`.  Stop collecting after your start-of-quoted-line regex returns false.  Make sure that you don't have to account for any email in which the responder inserts comments between quoted sections.

Comment: @abiessu  Can you provide an answer with a working solution or instructions on how to solve this?

Comment: @abiessu so your telling me the hide quoted or show quoted text is just from the email application, not part of the delivery content?

Comment: That is my assumption, but I don't know how you are receiving the content of the email within your script, so I can't be sure.

Comment: @abiessu id appreciate if you provided a solution because im having difficulty understanding how to implement it using your strpos method. I read your comment, and Id like to see a solution I can look at and understand.

Comment: `preg_match('/Quoting(.*)/', $str, $matches);`. `$matches[0]` contains the match `with reference`, whereas `$matches[1]` contains matches `without reference`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution would be along the following lines, given the content of the email saved as lines in an array named `$myarray` and storing into `$outarray`:

```
$doquote = FALSE;
foreach ($myarray as $val) {
  if (strpos($val, 'Quoting') !== FALSE)
     $doquote = TRUE;

  if ($doquote) {
    if (preg_match('[|>]', $val, $matches) == 1) {
      array_push($outarray, $matches[1]);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Note that you don't have to account for "Show quoted text" or "Hide quoted text" if they do not begin with the quoted-text character.